# Is there anyway to detect or intercept if a program is forcbily quit/terminated in a injected DLL?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, code-cleanup, dll-injection

I want to perform a cleanup procedure for my injected DLL before the injected application terminates. So I'm looking for a way to intercept `ExitProcess`, `TerminateProcess` or any termination in general.

The function I want to run:

```c
void ZetaLoaderExit()
{
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, (PVOID)&wnd.tm, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
    SetDM(0);
}
```

The function:

1. Sets `SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` back to default.
2. Resets the display resolution of a resolution back to default.

I first tried to look if I could run a function at an application startup/exit here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pragma-directive-in-c-c/, tried using `__attribute__((destructor))` in my injected DLL but it seems the function is never called when the program exits.

Next idea, I got was maybe try to detour `ExitProcess`/`TerminateProcess`? Detouring seems confusing to me but a possible solution.

Another thing, I could try to is making a proxy function but not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: If bypassing such calls was possible, it would be a massive security loophole:((

Comment: @MartinJames How so? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DllMain()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain?redirectedfrom=MSDN) gets called on a `LoadLibrary()` and on a `FreeLibrary()`. The second parameter can be used to know why the function is being called. I think the docs are pretty clear about that:

> The system also calls the entry-point function for a DLL when it is loaded or unloaded using the LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary functions.

You probably want to check out `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

Comment: `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` would only be valid, if the target process loaded the DLL itself. In my case, I am injecting a DLL using CreateRemoteThread so the process has no idea that a external library has been loaded.

Comment: @Aetopia no, you are wrong. Your dll is usual dll for process. If ExitProcess will be called - your dll entry point will be called

Comment: @Aetopia Maybe you should mention the fact that you are using `CreateRemoteThread()` in your question. I suppose in that case the `DllMain()` does not get called because it would be from another process which still holds the DLL. Although if you terminate the thread, you should have it called with `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. I do not know enough about `CreateRemoteThread()`, however. That's a new one for me.

Comment: @AlexisWilke - *I suppose in that case the DllMain() does not get called* - of course no. of course called. `CreateRemoteThread` absolute unrelated here at all.